# Getting Disputed Boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, boundaries

I am using the [OSM Boundaries Map 4.0](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/) to download the boundaries of the countries. The problem is that I want to include the disputed boundaries for countries such as Bhutan:

[image]

Is there anyway of downloading the disputed boundaries from OSM or any other accurate vendor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Natural Earth 10m Cultural](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) dataset has a polygon layer of territorial disputes, which includes Bhutan.

[image]